# Access call history on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

In my iOS application I need to get all call history (dialled,recieved,missed) from an iOS device and display as a list in my application.

So many answers are there previously for this question.But I didn't get exact answer for my question.

If anybody worked on this question previously please let me know the answer immediately.

Answer (score 9):

There is no public API for accessing the call history on iOS.

If you wanted to do this in a private app that couldn't be released on the App Store you could look at this [link](https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/).

There are apps on the store that use the above method, but I wouldn't rely on it passing review. I think the apps that do use it may have slipped through the net.

Comment: The code which you provided here in that link,is that code works in simulator or only in device?

Comment: I would assume device as you are unable to make calls on the simulator.

Comment: Iam new to Ios,Can u tell me how to create sqlite for this code.

Comment: You don't create the sqlite, you can only read it. It is created by the OS when you make and receive calls. There is a website with line by line instructions posted in the answer above. If you are unable to follow that, then you would be unable to follow my line by line instructions too. StackExchange is not for line by line tutorials.

Comment: I just used the code below this line in that link "Accessing the Call History
"

Comment: Iam not getting any response for this code.Can you please help me.

Comment: I'm at work at the moment and busy tonight I'm afraid. I would start another question with the issues you are now having, being clear to explain what you have done already.

Comment: In my office device i dont have sim in the device, then also we can get the call history.In that device i have some call logs.

Comment: @09121989: Did you get the part that said **private API**? You can't access `/private/var/root/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db` on a non-jailbroken phone.

Comment: you said it cant be released on the app store and the link is stating that it is allowed.... i just want to make sure