# How to get the Call history in iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

How can we get the call history in `iOS 10`. I want to track incoming and outgoing call using my app.

Comment: You can't, this would be a breach of privacy.

Comment: Please search stackoverflow rather than posting question directly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693702/access-call-history-on-ios

Comment: @Sohil R. Memon: I have already checked this link.

Comment: @Ved So what's the purpose of asking question then?

Comment: @Sohil R. Memon  i want to get incoming and outgoing call logs in my app.

Comment: @Ved Okay great! So you are saying that **Call History** will give different data rather than Incoming and Outgoing Calls?

Comment: So any idea about this..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130118/discussion-between-ved-and-sohil-r-memon).

Answer (score 5):

This information is not available with any public iOS API.

Comment: This must be a comment. Try to add this add comment not as an answer.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable answer to me.

Comment: Is there any way I can use private API to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get info only about contacts, but no history, calls, sms, etc. Here's what you can do with Address book:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html